# Export ActionScript 2.0 from .fla file symbol's (frames) to separate file and use it

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am very new to ActionScript. I have a .fla file which contains the AS2 code for the frames. What I need to do is that I have to export this code as a separate file. There may be a separate file(or class file) for each frame code. Is it possible to me do it automatically without losing animation interactivity and functionality? Or is there any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is a bit of effort. You'll need to write a custom JSFL script to manage that.

This is a bit involved to provide a working solution here, but you can find the ActionScript on the [frame object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_ExtendingFlash/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7f6e.html).